# how to render page without clicking in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I use next js and I am new.I had a question.How can I move a user to a new page without clicking after registering?What method should I use?
In other words, I want to move to a new page without clicking

Comment: How else do you want to redirect? Scrolling? Timer? Mouse hover?

Comment: @JMadelaine I want to post the information by axios and save it in the database(sign-up).After responding the user is moved to the profile page

Comment: @JMadelaine If you do not understand, can I explain more?

Comment: @JMadelaine You just tell me,in client side, how do I do this? For example, by mouse hover

Comment: Use Router check the doc for more info